# Is it legal to hit a shuttlecock around the net posts in badminton?

Tags: rules, badminton

In tennis and table tennis, it is legal to hit the ball around the net and net posts, i.e. the ball need not pass over the net as long as it gets to the legal court area on the opponent's side (without passing under or through the net).

Is this also the case in badminton? Or does it constitute a fault for the shuttle to be struck below the net's height even if it makes it to the other side without having to pass through/below the physical net? (In other words, for badminton ruling purposes is it imagined that the net is a flat vertical plane that extends infinitely past the sides of the court?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the BWF [Laws of Badminton](https://system.bwfbadminton.com/documents/folder_1_81/Regulations/Laws/Part%20II%20Section%201A%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton%20-%20June%202016%20Revised%202.pdf), it is not legal.

> It shall be a ‘fault’:
>
> 13.3 if in play, the shuttle:
>
> 13.3.2 fails to pass over the net;

Answer (score 0):

I think more important questions is, is it possible/necessary to do around the net shot in badminton? Realistically, there's literally zero case where it is needed... To do around the net shot you have create enough spin to make a curve trajectory. It's possible in tennis or table tennis because they use balls. Badminton, on the other hand, uses shuttlecock which couldn't spin in its horizontal axis, hence couldn't have curve trajectory... The only possibility that a shuttle could have a curvy trajectory is due to drift, but that only happen when the shuttle is high enough (much higher than the net), so it's not really around the net... The only scenario where you can theoretically do around the net shot is when you hit the shuttle outside the double side line of the court (in badminton, the net is exactly as wide as the court) which doesn't make any sense because you would just let it out and get point...

Answer (score 0):

The shuttle must pass over the net, the exception being if your opponents returns it.

If you were to hit the shuttle out, but your opponent returns it and it catches the tramline down the same side then there is an instance whereby despite them hitting their shot into the court it is technically a fault under the rules of the game as the shuttle failed to travel over the net.

I've never seen anyone call this as a fault in practice however.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Can you provide a source to your answer?